# Dependency Injection and service starting/shutdown

Tags: scala, dependency-injection

Some of the software components in my application require startup and shutdown activity.

**Question 1:** What are best practices to start and stop such "services" in Scala?

I am using Dependency Injection (DI) in my application and my current understanding is that DI *declares* dependencies between software components but should be [side-effect free](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ModulesShouldBeFastAndSideEffectFree) (i.e., the DI mechanism should not start/stop services by itself). So DI is orthogonal to service activation.

There seems to be an overlap, however: suppose that my application contains a `NotificationService`, which in turn uses a `SchedulingService`. So I inject a scheduling service implementation into my notification service implementation and *manually* start and stop these services. However, the DI framework has all the information at hand to know which services need to be instantiated (and thus started/stopped) and which depend on which (and therefore the order in which the services need to be started/stopped). It could therefore offer methods to start/stop them, saving me some boilerplate code!

**Question 2:** Have their been any attempts to extend DI (e.g., Guice) to record the injected services and offer methods to start/stop them?

Comment: You can easily implement such behavior using '.injectAll' feature of http://github.com/aloiscochard/sindi

Comment: Thanks, @AloisCochard, this looks interesting. Can you outline in a bit more detail how you would define, and start and stop services? Is there an example/unit test out there?

Answer (score 1):

On question 1, dependency injection strategies are well-established in Java, and these generally can translate directly into Scala. However, I think Scala can go better: its primary constructors are very well suited to constructor-based dependency injection, often felt to be the least cluttered of the various approaches (others being setter injection, annotation based injection etc).

In a recent project, we originally had used Spring but changed over to take a *less is more* policy, dropping Spring entirely.

- We used Scala in a test-driven DI object-oriented manner with almost no XML (the one remaining `web.xml` was necessary for the webapp of course).
- A single `Bootstrap` class configured all the resources and services in the correct order with the necessary dependency injection.
- `Bootstrap` was of course started from `web.xml`.
- Everything was unit tested *except* for `Bootstrap`, which was tested instead by integration tests.

Given a suite of components, wiring several alternative configurations simply involves writing different `Bootstraps`. Doing this purely in Scala brings considerable benefits of code transparency and refactoring support within the IDE, and is relatively little effort.

On question 2, I don't have a specific answer. But I can recommend a *less is more* approach; if frameworks are just not needed, the question may be less important.

Comment: Thanks, @Rick-777, for sharing your experience.